# NHibernate recreates entities without one property

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have a problem with NH 3.4.1

I have mapping like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly=..." namespace="...">
    <class name="ProductCategory" table="dbo.ProductCategory">

    .....
    <bag name="ParentRelations" table="ProductCategoryRelation" lazy="true" batch-size="100">
      <key column="ProdCatRelCatNumber" />
      <one-to-many class="CategoryRelation" />
    </bag>      
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="..." namespace="...">
    <class name="CategoryRelation" table="dbo.ProductCategoryRelation">
        <composite-id>
            <key-many-to-one name="Parent" class="ProductCategory" column="ProdCatRelParentCatNumber" />
            <key-many-to-one name="Child" class="ProductCategory" column="ProdCatRelCatNumber" />
        </composite-id>
        <property name="Priority" column="ProdCatRelPriority" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So I have an entity that have one-to-many relationship to another entity. And relations table contains Priority column which is important.

The problem is when I update only Priority column for CategoryRelation entity - NH generates one UPDATE, but when I am creating new relation, or deleting existing - it create DELETE for all relations and INSERT for each of it. It's OK. I know about idbag, but I can't use it here.

The main problem is - when it creates INSERTs - it skips Priority column. So after insert/delete all my priorities are lost. Do you know where may be the problem? I'm pretty sure it is mapping problem, but can't find it and fix.

All I need is to make it remember priorities and insert them with the relations.

Thanks.